# CIColorMatrix Filter result is weird

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, core-image

I am trying to create a CIFilter which converts the following QR Code:

[image]

To:

[image]

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
let invert = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert")
invert!.setDefaults()
invert!.setValue(ciImage, forKey: "inputImage")

let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorMatrix")
filter?.setDefaults()
filter?.setValue(invert?.outputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

let r = CGFloat(70.0/255.0)
let g = CGFloat(224.0/255.0)
let b = CGFloat(182.0/255.0)

filter?.setValue(CIVector(x: r, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputRVector")
filter?.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: g, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputGVector")
filter?.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: b, w: 0), forKey: "inputBVector")
filter?.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1), forKey: "inputAVector")
```

What the code does is first invert the normal QR code so that it's black on white, then it takes that image and applies a filter on it.
The result of the code is this:

[image]

Which is not the color that I wanted. I would appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the following methods to achieve `QR filter effect` using `coreImage`.

**Output:**

[image]

**Method 1:** `Using Custom Filter`

`Step1:` Create seperate `class` to your `custom kernel` as follow.

```
class CustomFilter: CIFilter {
var inputImage: CIImage?

override public var outputImage: CIImage! {
    get {
        if let inputImage = self.inputImage {
            let args = [inputImage as AnyObject]
            return createCustomKernel().apply(withExtent: inputImage.extent, arguments: args)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
      }
    }
 }


func createCustomKernel() -> CIColorKernel {
let kernelString =
    "kernel vec4 chromaKey( __sample s) { \n" +
        "  vec4 newPixel = s.rgba;" +
        "  newPixel[0] = 0.0;" +
        "  newPixel[2] = newPixel[2] / 2.0;" +
        "  return newPixel;\n" +
"}"
return CIColorKernel(string: kernelString)!
 }
```

In your `ViewController` you can declare your custom filter as below.

```
 var context = CIContext(options: nil)

 func customQRFilter() {

    let myInvertFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert")
    myInvertFilter!.setValue(CIImage(image: imageView.image!), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let output = myInvertFilter!.outputImage 

    let filter = CustomFilter()
    filter.setValue(output, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    
    // Get the filtered output image and return it
    let outputImage = filter.outputImage!
    let cgimg = context.createCGImage(outputImage,from: output!.extent)
    let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
    imageView.image = processedImage
   }
```

**Method 2:** Using `CIColorMatrix` filter.

```
    func colorMatrixFilter() {
    
    let myInvertFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert")
    myInvertFilter!.setValue(CIImage(image: imageView.image!), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let output = myInvertFilter!.outputImage 
    
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorMatrix")
    filter?.setDefaults()
    filter?.setValue(output, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    
    let r = CGFloat(0.0)
    let g = CGFloat(0.9)
    let b = CGFloat(0.416)
    
    filter?.setValue(CIVector(x: r, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputRVector")
    filter?.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: g, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputGVector")
    filter?.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: b, w: 0), forKey: "inputBVector")
    filter?.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1), forKey: "inputAVector")
    
    let outputs = filter?.outputImage 
    let cgimg = context.createCGImage(outputs!,from: output!.extent)
    let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
    imageView2.image = processedImage
}
```

**Note:** I advice you to use a `colour Picker tool` to pick `RGB value of any colour` you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a context *without* a colorspace, to get the color correct:

```
...
let ciContext = CIContext(options: [CIContextOption.outputColorSpace: NSNull(), CIContextOption.workingColorSpace: NSNull()])
let cgimg = ciContext.createCGImage(outputs!,from: output!.extent)
let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
```

(Swift 4)

Comment: lenooh, you are a genius, how did you find out that context without a colorspace gets the color correct?